# iterating through an array of objects

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, iteration

I've done this before with no issues, so I must be forgetting something: 
I'm grabbing an array of variable-value pairs and attempting to iterate through and return some info.  the code:

```
$events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'trail' AND meta_value = ".$thisid.";" );
print_r($events);
```

produces:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Post_id] => 1150 ) [1] => stdClass
>   Object ( [Post_id] => 1156 ) )

To iterate through, I'm then doing this:

```
foreach($events as $key => $val){
echo $key->$val;
}
```

Which produces nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `$key` is the key in the array, and `$val` is the value at that key. You do not have an object called `$key`, and none of your objects have a property with the name that is in `$val`.

You could do

```
foreach($events as $key => $val){
   echo $val->Post_id;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This was the key!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($events as $event){
    echo $event->Post_id;
}
```

Comment: this one still returns blank

Answer (score 0):

because -> is a reserved "word" in php to access a class' method. I'm surprised you're not getting an error. Check to see if you have error reporting on as well.
Try this:

```
foreach($events[0] as $key => $val){
    echo $key. '->' . $val;
}
```

Comment: Interesting - this got me: `Post_id->1150`